# d3 maps(berghaus star projection)

Tags: d3.js

I was trying to create a berghaus star projection chloropeth just like

http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/5685876

But I am not able to get antartica and austarlia right .
Can someone guide on what should be my approach.

```
svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
      .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land))
      .attr("class", "land")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
      .attr("d", path);
```

this is original code, my code is

```
svg.insert("g", ".graticule")
                     .attr("class", "land")
                    .selectAll("path")
                    .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features)
                    .enter().append("path")
                    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
                     .attr("d", path);
```

after changing this it is showing everything distorted.
Please advise

Comment: You are trying to do this? http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4463049 What isn't working for antartica and australia?

Comment: If that link isn't enough for you to figure it out, please describe the results you're getting (post a link to a screenshot if possible) and explain why they aren't "right".

Comment: I have updated the question can you please advise

Comment: You'll want to check out these issue reports on the d3 github: [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1158) and [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/issues/3).  It looks like the main problems with the Berghaus projection should be fixed in the latest versions of d3.  **Make sure you're using the latest version from d3js.org,** and then if you're still having problems you might want to leave a comment on the more recent of those issues.

Comment: I am using the latest version, still I am geeting improper shapes.is this someting to do about groups rather than path . You can See the difference in code.How can I correct it?